# laravel 5 configuration service providers for local only

Tags: php, laravel, service-provider

I just read the Laravel 5 doc on configuration based on your environment http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration

I understand how the .env files can be used to configure some variables but how do I configure what service providers get loaded based on the environment?

For example in my ''local'' environment I use this debugbar plugin which needs a service provider but I don't want to define it in config/app.php for production.

In Laravel 4.2 I could just create config/local/app.php but that doesn't seem to work anymore, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you set APP_DEBUG to false in your .env file the debugbar will go away automatically.

Also I wrote a middleware class to take care of that.

The handle method could look like this in your case:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (app()->environment('production'))
        \Debugbar::disable();
    else
        \Debugbar::enable();

    return $next($request);
}
```

Then you just add it to the list of middleware in app/Http/kernel.php and you're good to go.

I have some additional conditions and more environments so this exact code is not tested but it should work and you should get the idea.

Take care.

Comment: Thanks MaGnetas, it does indeed work but what I'm concerned about is that the service provider definition is defined in my production app.php evethough it's never actually used there. It feels like a step back in terms of performance/flexibility where I can't have a separate config file alltogether.

Comment: No, the environments now share all the config files. In case you need a separate config value for every environment it should come from .env file I believe.

Answer (score 4):

This article was helpful for me:

https://mattstauffer.co/blog/conditionally-loading-service-providers-in-laravel-5

And this is what I've done and it works:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
            $this->app->register('Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelent! That fixed the problem on the server!!